# Hay alguna alternativa a esta para realizar un Random sub-set en R

Tags: r, random

Para extraer un sub-set del dataframe df.

```
set.seed(11111)
rnd<-sample(1:nrow(df),nrow(df))
df<-df[ rnd, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Si la idea es hacer una muestra aleatoria con n=n y sin reemplazo se me ocurren dos alternativas.

## R base

```
df[sample(1:nrow(df)), ]  #En el subset con [] ubicamos números de índice aleatorios en la parte de las filas
```

## Tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  sample_frac(1)
```

`sample_frac()` regresa una fracción aleatoria del data.frame, pero si la fracción es 1 entonces es todo el df con la ubicación de las filas aleatorizada.

En su simpleza es bastante potente `sample_frac`. Por ejemplo, para hacer un bootstrap en el que tendrías que remuestrear con n=n y con reemplazo podrías usar:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  sample_frac(1, replace = TRUE)
```

Y si necesitas que el muestreo aleatorio respete tamaños de grupos definidos por otra variable:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(otra_variable) %>%
  sample_frac(1, replace = TRUE)
```